# Get last row of CSV file and append it onto the end of the same CSV file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I need to retrieve the last row of a CSV file, and append it onto the end to extend it any *n* number of times.  I attempted to do this with Pandas:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
last_row = df.iloc[-1]

last_row.to_csv('file.csv', mode='a', header=False)
```

However, this appends the last row as a single column into the CSV file.  Is there a way to properly append the last row column-wise into the CSV file, preferably using Pandas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question:

I have figured out how to maintain the order of columns and append to the end of the existing dataframe.  It is worth noting that `pd.tail()` does not maintain the order of columns.

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')

df_fluxes =  df.iloc[[-1] * n] 

df_fluxes.to_csv(run_dir+'em_line_fluxes.csv', mode='a', header=False, index=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can use `tail` and `concat` to extend your dataframe.

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
last_row = df.tail(1)

last_row = pd.concat([last_row] * n)


last_row.to_csv('file.csv', mode='a', header=False)
```

Comment: This method does add the rows, but they are in the incorrect order as the original dataframe.  Is there a way to correctly add the rows in the correct order?'